# Running a Android App while the screen is black

Tags: android, database, service

I'm trying to run a android app while the screen is black, i used a service and i tryed to add also a WakeLock of the type "PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK".

The service play a song and save data from the accelerometer to the db, but when i press the red phone button to make the screen black, it play the song but it don't save data to the db. Have anyone a idea of why it don't save data to the db?

Tnk's

Valerio

Answer (score 0):

With this you ensure that the code between acquire() and release() are executed even if the phone is in stanby mode, since the cpu will stay active.

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
 wl.acquire();
   ..CPU will stay on during this section..
 wl.release();
```